# How to fetch multiple log files from same server through graylog-collector-sidecar?

Tags: logging, filebeat, graylog2

I am using graylog 2.4.6 and installed graylog-collector-sidecar and wants to see multiple application logs from same server. Actually, we have multiple applications running on same server where i installed collector and that server is EC2 instance of ubuntu on which we have ubuntu 14.04 ~ using filebeat with graylog-collector.

Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Let me know how you implemented centralised logging in your organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Collector Sidecar Configurations" on the Graylog server, choose your configuration, select "Configure Beats Inputs" and enter multiple paths to the logfiles in the "Path to logfile", like this:

```
['/var/log/*.log','/var/log/apache2/*.log']
```

They are then configured in the Filebeats configuration on the hosts as multiple logfile input items.